# React JS Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

he hecho una aplicación en ReactJS, una vez terminada he hecho npm run build, quiero acceder estatico sin el serve -s build, para ello entro a http://Dominio/frontend/build/

Me aparece la cabecera pero ya no me aparece el menú ni nada mas, en consola sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También tengo en el package.json
`"homepage": "./",`

No se si tengo mal las rutas o estoy haciendo algo mal, si alguien lo sabe le agradeceria la ayuda.

Comment: Esta aplicación fue creada con `create-react-app`?

Comment: @JuanMarco gracias por responder, lo he clonado de aquí https://github.com/gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app

Answer (score 1):

Para usar la sintaxis de `import... from...`, tienes que declarar el fichero Javascript como un módulo. De este modo podrás importar otros módulos:

```
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```

Por otro lado, no sé si el código que se ve en tu navegador es generado por fichero `.map`. Si no es así y realmente ése es el código que intentas usar en el navegador, para que los `import` funcionen necesitas poner tras el `from` la URL del módulo con el nombre completo del fichero, sin omitir el .js, algo como por ejemplo:

```
import randomSquare from '../square.js';
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero como pongo el type="module" si cuando hago el npm run build se vuelve a generar el index.html y me lo borra?